# Wrong output in my stringreverse program. what is fault in my code?

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
char* strreverse(char*);
int main()
{
char *rev_string;
char *name="computer";
clrscr();
rev_string=strreverse(name);
printf("%s", rev_string);
getch();
return 0;
 }
 char* strreverse(char *name)
 {
int length=strlen(name);
char *ptr;
char *rstr;
for(ptr=name+(length-1);ptr>=name;ptr--)
    {
     *rstr=*ptr;

     printf("%c",rstr);
     rstr++;
     }
     *(rstr)=NULL;
     return rstr;
}
```

the above is my code. i tried to write a program for string reverse without using arrays. But i am not getting the output retupmoc. what is wrong in my code? how to insert null char in char*?

Comment: rstr is pointing to undefined memory

Comment: `ptr>=name;ptr--` is UB.

Comment: what is meant by UB please..explain in detail sir @BLUEPIXY

Comment: when ptr == &name[-1] then use `ptr` is Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char* strreverse(const char*);

int main(){
    char *rev_string;
    char *name="computer";
    clrscr();
    rev_string=strreverse(name);
    printf("%s\n", rev_string);
    free(rev_string);
    getch();
    return 0;
}

char* strreverse(const char *name){
    int length=strlen(name);
    const char *ptr;
    char *ret, *rstr = malloc(length + 1);
    if(ret=rstr){
        for(ptr=name+length;ptr != name;){
            *rstr++ = *--ptr;
        }
        *rstr = '\0';
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Comment: it gives the exact out put. how the if(ret=rstr) works here @bluepixy

Comment: @AnilaChandran ; and then save it as the return value of the function it need to check the return value of `malloc` whether `NULL` is also there.

Comment: if i give input as c omputer..it prints only c..y space is not considered and the letters after the space is not reversed pls explain me

Comment: @AnilaChandran ; Program itself is no problem even if there is space. Than there is a problem in the way of input?

Comment: pixy;i gave "co mputer"  it prints oc only ..what is the reason..or is this input wrong?

Comment: @AnilaChandran if u use `scanf("%s", str);`, change to `scanf("[^\n]", str);`

Comment: now it works correctly..why should we use this scanf("%[^\n]")?

Comment: @AnilaChandran ; `"%s"` in order to delimit the space character(Eg ' ', '\t', '\n'..). `"[^\n]"` to read the non-newline character.

Answer (score 1):

You did not allocate memory to hold your reversed string. Try

```
char *rstr = calloc(1, length+1);
```

Also it should be

```
printf("%c", *rstr); // dereference
*(rstr)= '\0'; // instead of NULL
```

Comment: And you should use printf("%c",*rstr);

Comment: i tried your answer. but i am getting some symbols as output.

Comment: in printf i am getting the reverse. but when returning the reverse string is not printed..why

Comment: @AnilaChandran ; because pointer of the return value points to a null-terminator at the end of the string.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY : yes i changed it into *(rstr+length)='\0'; but no answer for this also..is this correct

Answer (score 1):

Here you find sweet and short solution for string reverse:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int strreverse(char* , char*);

int main()
{
   char rev_string[10] = {0};
   char name[10]="computer";
   strreverse(name, rev_string);
   printf("%s\n", rev_string);
   return 0;
}

int strreverse(char *name, char *rStr)
{
   int i = 0;
   int length = strlen(name);
   while(i < length)
   {
      rStr[i] = name[length-i-1];
      i++;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Try to run and have fun.

Comment: yes . i wanted to write a program without using arrays anywhere

Comment: Then you have to allocate memory to char* name and char* rev_string then also you can do it.